# What is this touchscreen "kiosk" called?

Tags: word-choice

Some shopping centers have a touchscreen "kiosk" with a map and store finder software that helps customers to find their "unfindable" store.

[image]

Do these have a name? I have tried to find some examples on the web, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: A search for [navigation kiosk](https://www.google.com/search?q=navigation+kiosk) brings up a lot of relevant images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, these are usually just called *directories* in context. A Google search for [*directory kiosk*](https://www.google.com/search?q=directory+kiosk) seems to work well.

Comment: Do you mean "called directories in _the given_ context"? I ask because, as a cartographer i wish to know how to name maps that are fixed to the ground/building, and i think of them as _in situ_ maps, and i almost corrected your "directories in context" to "directories in situ"!

Comment: Yes - in the context in which such objects are usually encountered (i.e., shopping malls), they are usually called 'directories'.

Answer (score -2):

It is sometimes call wayfinding. Directory Solutions is another. see touchsource.com for example

Comment: Touchsource.com's website uses "wayfinding" to refer to the entire installation for the facility, such as "plumbing" or "wiring."  The lowtech "follow the yellow line to X" practice is also covered under "wayfinding."